# Censoring a file

Tags: awk, cycle

I would like to use awk to modify a text file.
The modified text file should transform any word starting with "te" or "Te" and doesn't include a number into "yyyyy" - to sort of censor the file.

So for example a file

```
Hello everyone,
today is a great day to get tested by mr. Tenet here!
Don't te11 anyone!
```

should be modified into

```
Hello everyone,
today is a great day to get yyyyy by mr. yyyyy here!
Don't te11 anyone!
```

Then I'd like to include information about the modification - to say how many lines the file has and how many lines were modified (is it needed to use a for cycle to do this?)

This info should be added to the end of the file and look like this:

```
The file has 3 lines and 2 out of these were modified.
```

I am quite lost and would appreciate any help. Thank you

Comment: This may help - https://askubuntu.com/questions/20414/find-and-replace-text-within-a-file-using-commands

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'BEGIN{ IGNORECASE=1; m1=0; m2=0 }
     { x=gsub(/te[a-zA-Z]* /,"yyyyy ",$0); m1+=(x!=0); m2+=x; print }
     END{ print "The file has " NR " lines and " m1 " out of these were modified, with " m2 " changes"}' inputfile
```

or

```
awk 'BEGIN{ IGNORECASE=1; m1=0; m2=0 }
     { x=gsub(/te[[:alhpa:]]* /,"yyyyy ",$0); m1+=(x!=0); m2+=x; print }
     END{ print "The file has " NR " lines and " m1 " out of these were modified, with " m2 " changes"}' inputfile
```

If you do not need the output of the changed text, then remove `print` from the second line.

output:

```
Hello everyone,
today is a great day to get yyyyy by mr. yyyyy here!
Don't te11 anyone!
The file has 3 lines and 1 out of these were modified, with 2 changes
```

EDIT: because of the comment on `Teheran!` i changed my input file to:

```
Hello everyone,
today is a great day, to get tested by mr. Tenet here!
time to light some external fire in Teheran!
Don't te11 anyone!
```

and the script to:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ IGNORECASE=1; m1=0; m2=0 }
     { x=gsub(/\<te[[:alpha:]^[0-9][:punct:]]*/,"yyyyy ",$0); m1+=(x!=0); m2+=x; print }
     END{ print "The file has " NR " lines and " m1 " out of these were modified, with " m2 " changes"}' inputfile
```

this seems to work ok:

```
Hello everyone,
today is a great day, to get yyyyy  by mr. yyyyy  here!
time to light some external fire in yyyyy
Don't te11 11 anyone!
The file has 4 lines and 3 out of these were modified, with 4 changes
```

Comment: Regular expression `/te[[:alpha:]]* /` will also affect words with `te` inside, for example it turn `eternal fire` into `eyyyyy fire`. It will also fail for word followed by punctuation, for example `Where is Tehran?` would result in unaltered text.

Comment: I edited my answer to make it work better. Thanks for the input!

Comment: But i seen i do have a lot to learn about regular expressions... because `te11` is now also change to `yyyyy`.

Comment: changing the regular expression from `/\<te[[:alpha:]^[:punct:]]*/`   to  `/\<te[[:alpha:]^[0-9][:punct:]]*/` solves that problem to.  (also updated in answer)

Comment: Alright, and if the "te" wouldn't have to be at the start of the word, but also for example at the end?